# executing and reading a Microsoft SQL query into a pandas dataframe with Columns Names

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to execute a query and then placing it into a dataframe.  For some reason, it is only loading column 0.  The entire resultset is loaded into that one column.

Here's what I am doing

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("connection info")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute = "sql statement"
names = [ x[0] for x in cursor.description]
rows = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = names)
```

I get this error.

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 421), indices imply (5, 421)
```

It is suppose to be 5 columns, however when I ran it without the 'columns = names' and the dataframe is returning one column.  Within this column it is storing the entire dataset of 5 columns from the sql query.

this is an example of what the result set looks like when I run it without the 'columns name':

```
(9026461, 875, 110, Decimal('1.08'), 3100)
```

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_sql_query()`?

Comment: yes, I tried pd.read_sql_query(), however that doesn't work bc my sql statement has a where clause.  well, I couldn't get it to work.  the execute finally retrieved the results, but for some reason I can't get the result set in a datadrame with all the columns...so stumped!

Comment: It should work regardless of whether or not there is a where clause. It should all be contained in the `sql` argument.

Comment: do you know why the dataframe is not creating the columns. this is basically what I am doing https://gist.github.com/mvaz/2006493

Comment: If you do a fetchone() and look at it, what do you get?

Comment: @A.Leistra, thank you for replying!  when I replace it with fetchone(), I get  ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked with the following:

```
 engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://serverName/DatabaseName?  driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
 connection = engine.connect()

 resultSet = connection.execute("select column1, column2 from ....")
 df = pd.DataFrame(resultSet.fetchall())
 df.columns = resultSet .keys()
```